# Ошибка при выполнении functional теста в codeception

Tags: codeception, функциональное-тестирование

Здраствуйте, прошу помощи. Начинаю изучать тему тестирования. До момента подключения модуля yii2 - все работало.  После подключения модуля появилась ошибка, тесты не проходят. 
Содержимое файла **codeception.yml**:

    `paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    memory_limit: 1024M
    colors: true
modules:
    enabled:
        #- Yii2
    config:
        #Yii2:
        #    configFile: 'config/test11.php'`

---

Содержимое файла **fuctional.suite.yml**:

`actor: FunctionalTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - Yii2:
               configFile: 'config/test.php'
               #entryUrl: 'https://site.loc/' 
    #recreateComponents: ['urlManager']
               #recreateComponents: ['urlManager']
            - \Helper\Functional
            - Filesystem`

---

Содержимое файла теста **SitesCest.php**:

```
    namespace cabinet;

    use FunctionalTester;

    class SitesModelCest
    {
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
        {

        }

        public function _after(FunctionalTester $I)
        {

        }
        public function viewSites(FunctionalTester $I)
        {
            $I->seeRecord('\app\models\Site', array('name' => 'agro'));
            $I->amOnPage('index-test.php?site/index');
        }
    }
```

---

> Для метода $I->amOnPage ("я на странице") пробовал разные форматы
>   ссылок, ['/'], '/', 'site/index', ['site/index'] - результат не
>   изменился

При запуске теста получаю ошибку:

```
[yii\base\InvalidArgumentException] Trying to copy a directory to itself or a subdirectory.
```

При попытке подключить модуль

```
- PhpBrowser:
        url: https://site.loc/
```

Получаю ошибку конфликта модулей

```
PhpBrowser module conflicts with Yii2
```

> Использую версию Codeception 2.3.9

Если удалить метод $I->amOnPage, то тест пройдет, запись находит.

Что я делаю не так? Для модуля yii2 есть метод amOnPage и amOnRoute, но они у меня не отрабатывают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, ответ крылся, как я и ожидал, в простом, в конфиге. Надо в конфига для тестов (config/test.php) дописать строку, которая будет указывать на папку с assets-ами.

```
'aliases' => [
        '@webroot/assets' => __DIR__.'/../../assets',
    ],
```

В моем случае именно так, потому, что структура папок проекта, немного не типичная